# Ordenar un API antes de enviarlo del servicio al componente en Ionic/Angular

Tags: json, angular, api, ionic, pipe

Tengo un servicio en Ionic/Angular en el que paso la url de un API a un componente. esta URL tiene un json. En el servicio quiero ordenar el json según unos parámetros y luego fraccionarlo en trozos de 10 objetos para enviar esos trozos al componente. Lo del scroll me sale pero si quiero ordenar el API antes de pasarlo por el pipe no veo la forma.

Esta sería la idea, pero no funciona bien:

```js
export class ZonesService {
  url =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nexus-devs/wow-classic-items/master/data/json/zones.json';
  urlOrdenada: any = [];
  urlOriginal: any;
  faction: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public factionService: FactionService) {
    this.faction = factionService.faction;
    console.log('La facción en el zones.service es', this.faction);
  }

  getZoneList(page) {
    this.urlOriginal = this.http.get(this.url);
    console.log('Estos son los datos de la url:' + this.http.get(this.url));
    for (let i = 0; i < this.urlOriginal.length; i++) {
      if (
        this.faction === this.urlOriginal[i].territory &&
        this.urlOriginal[i].level[0] >= 1
      ) {
        this.urlOrdenada.push(this.urlOriginal[i]);
      }
      if (
        this.urlOriginal[i].territory === 'Contested' &&
        this.urlOriginal[i].level[0] >= 1
      ) {
        this.urlOrdenada.push(this.urlOriginal[i]);
      }
    };

    this.urlOrdenada.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (parseFloat(a.level[0]) > parseFloat(b.level[0])) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.level[0] < b.level[0]) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
    return this.urlOrdenada.pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.slice(page * 10, page * 10 + 10))
    );
  }
}
```

Pero no funciona. En la var urlOriginal quiero meter el array original del json. En urlOrdenada quiero meter el array ordenado, y a partir de ahí quiero mandar el array de 10 en 10 (eso sí funciona). Me da que hay algo en la conversión del json a arrayJson que no estoy haciendo bien.

Creo que el fallo está en:

```
this.urlOriginal = this.http.get(this.url);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

al mostrarlo en el html podrías pasarle el pipe que haga todo
ejemplo:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array| pipeName:page">
```

donde pipeName seria algo como:

```
transform(array: tipoArray[], page:number = 0): tipoArray[] {
  newArray = sortFunction(array)//aquí iría la función que uses para ordenar el array
  return newArray.slice(page, page + 10)//devuelves 10 items del array ordenado
}
```

al incrementar o decrementar page desde el componente, te irían llegando nuevos items del array

Comment: Gracias Maxi, pero quiero ordenar todo el array ANTES de ir mostrando en pantalla los objetos de 10 en 10. Me gustaría ordenarlo en el servicio. Creo que hay algo que noentiendo en cuanto a los formatos. Voy a editar la pregunta original con más detalles para ver si consigo explicarme mejor. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!